# SQL Grouping in sequence & Sequential ID for group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sequential-number

I have below SQL database and would like to group them in sequence and assign ID to each group.

| Time | Line | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:00PM | 1 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:01PM | 1 | White |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:02PM | 1 | Red |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:04PM | 1 | Red |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:05PM | 1 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:06PM | 1 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:00PM | 2 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:01PM | 2 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:02PM | 2 | White |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:03PM | 2 | White |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:03PM | 2 | White |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:03PM | 2 | Black |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:03PM | 2 | Black |

Result that I am looking for is

| Time | Line | Colour | Qty | Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:00PM | 1 | Black | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:01PM | 1 | White | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:02PM | 1 | Red | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:04PM | 1 | Red | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:05PM | 1 | Black | 2 | 4 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:06PM | 1 | Black | 2 | 4 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:00PM | 2 | Black | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:01PM | 2 | Black | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:02PM | 2 | White | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:02PM | 2 | White | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:03PM | 2 | White | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:04PM | 2 | Black | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-11-02 3:00:05PM | 2 | Black | 2 | 3 |

Qty is basically # of same colour from line in a row.

Group ID is sequential ID for colour change by line.

I just couldn't figure out as it needs to be sequential in 'Time' then 'Line' columns and unable to aggregate.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
SELECT * , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Line, groupId) Qty
FROM (
    SELECT *
      , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Insertdate) 
      - rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Line, colour ORDER BY Insertdate) AS GroupId
   FROM tablename
) t ORDER BY line, Insertdate
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6675ee9233b713e9582711bd334b0e4)*